# Value of type "WKWebView" has no member "scrollView"

Tags: xcode, macos, webkit, swift3

I'm trying to get the scrollView of my WKWebView, but Xcode tells me that WKWebView has no such member.

```
let webview = WKWebView();
let sv = webView.scrollView
```

However, on [this reference page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview), scrollView is clearly a member of WKWebview.
How can I get this scrollView?

The final goal of this is to totally disable scrolling and hide scrollbars in my view. Is there any way of doing it without using the WKWebView's scrollView?
**EDIT:** I've achieved this by modifying the css of the loaded page. The ScrollView problem is still here though.

I'm using Xcode 8.1 on OSX 10.11.6.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** `import WebKit` is already present in my code, and my webview otherwise works very well. The only problem is the scrollview.

**EDIT 2:** I'm making an OSX-only app.

**EDIT 3:** It seems I was missing the fact `ScrollView` is iOS-only.
Thus, the problem isn't a really a problem anymore.
I will keep this question open to let anyone post a more "swift-style" solution than using CSS.

Comment: Check the [reference of `scrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1614784-scrollview) carefully. In `SDK` part, it shows only `iOS 8.0+`. No `macOS`. `scrollView` is not available in macOS.

Comment: Right ! Nicely pointed out. Do you know any replacement of `ScrollView` for OSX?

Comment: No, I do not. Your solution, using modified CSS, seems good enough.

Comment: How did you modify the CSS?

Comment: @adib I unfortunately do not work on this project anymore. However, I guess I was using a CSS stylesheet imported directly in the webpage I was loading (using a `<link>` tag) in the `WebView`. Thus, I could have modified the page behaviour (including hiding the scrollbars) just by altering the CSS stylesheet. Hope it helps.